# How to change time format from 1730 to 17:30:00 in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, date, time, dataset

In a dataset I found the column Time has 1700, 1410, 845, 1030 etc.

The dataset is too large.

How can I convert this format (1700, 1410, 845, 1030) to 17:00:00, 14:10:00, 8:45:00, 10:30:00 format in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sub` with `sprintf`.  `sprintf` is used as the number of digits are not same (3 or 4), for 3 digits, the `sprintf` pads a 0 at the front (`%04d`) to make it consistent while appending `:00` at the end, then use `sub` to capture the first digits or characters (`(..)`), and replace with the backreference of the captured group (`\\1`) followed by a `:`

```
sub("^(..)", "\\1:", sprintf("%04d:00", df1$Time))
#[1] "17:30:00" "14:10:00" "08:45:00" "10:30:00"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Time = c(1730, 1410, 845, 1030)), class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative(data from @akrun's answer):

```
 format(strptime(gsub("^(\\d{3}$)","0\\1",df1$Time),format="%H%M"),"%H:%M:%S")
[1] "17:30:00" "14:10:00" "08:45:00" "10:30:00"
```